# How can I pass multiple JSON files as --data-binary in curl into JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to pass the file as binary data in JMeter, how can I achieve this.

How can I convert the following curl into the JMeter script?

```
for file in bulk_upload_*
do

    curl -s --silent --output /dev/null -XPOST "$ES_HOST/es-index/_doc/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary "@$file"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Copy the files you're uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Amend your command [for curl to use JMeter as the proxy](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/proxies) like:

   ```
   curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8888 -s --silent --output /dev/null ....
   ```
4. Run your command
5. That's it, JMeter will capture the requests and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Managers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: If I send a large file, getting a memory issue..
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in thread Thread[Thread-33,6,main]. See log file for details.

Comment: How to pass the file content as binary in JMeter?